# how to align text vertically center in android

Tags: android, android-layout, text

I have arabic text, therefore I set gravity to right in order to start text from right side. Text starts from right now. But another issue is text starts to render from the top of the page. But I need to vertically center the text.
Although I tried several variations I couldnt make it vertically center.

Here is the sample of my xml file.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Problem is with above textview.

Here I have put whole xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/page1background"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_Title_Top"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/backbut"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/backarrowpress" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/copyButton"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/copy"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody show me where I have done the mistake? I think problem is clear. If not tell me in comments.

Herewith I have appended updated code after review your answers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/page1background"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_Title_Top"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/backbut"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/backarrowpress" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/copyButton"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/copy"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I am in same situation. No text is vertically centered

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Your TextView Attributes need to be something like,

```
<TextView ... 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" ../>
```

Now, Description why these need to be done,

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Makes your TextView to `match_parent` or `fill_parent` if You don't want to be it like, `match_parent` you have to give some specified values to `layout_height` so it get space for vertical center gravity. `android:layout_width="match_parent"` necessary because it align your TextView in Right side so you can recognize respect to Parent Layout of TextView.

Now, its about `android:gravity` which makes the content of Your TextView alignment. `android:layout_gravity` makes alignment of TextView respected to its Parent Layout.

**Update:**

As below comment says use `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent`. (Problem in some device.)

Comment: Please avoid use of 'match_parent'.Use fill_parent or wrap_content instead.Because match _parent did not support in some devices.

Comment: I tried your answer with match_parent and fill_parent too since my app supports older versions but no luck. I still face the same issue. Text is still shows  on top.

Comment: Just for debug and test purpose can you write hard coded values at your LinearLayout `android:layout_height="200dp"` parent of TextView.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is the padding of the font on the textview. Just add to your textview:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Having a `TextView` with `android:layout_height="24dp"` and `android:textSize="20dp"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` I observed that text was still aligned bottom. `android:includeFontPadding="false"` fixed my problem!

Answer (score 18):

just use like this to make anything to center

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"
```

updated :

```
android:layout_gravity="center|right"
android:gravity="center|right"
```

Updated : Just remove MarginBottom from your textview.. Do like this.. for your textView

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:text="hello" 
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Both Parent and Child View has a Same `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. So the change doesn't reflected. (User can't recognize as gravity is set to `center_vertical`).

Comment: have you tried making changes to your LinearLayout. Try that It ll work. updating the answer

Comment: make both changes to textView and LinearLayout

Comment: got it remove marginBottom from your textView. It ll work.. Updating the answer

Comment: can brief why you ask me to remove margin bottom. I have set it to a purpose. but I can't see clear reason to remove it.. :(

Comment: if you remove margin bottom then you can see textview in center.. or put margin top also to see your textview center

Answer (score 8):

Try to put  `android:gravity="center_vertical|right"` inside parent LinearLayout else as you are inside RelativeLayout you can put `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` inside your `scrollView`.

Comment: i did but there is still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In relative layout you need specify textview height:

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

Or specify lines attribute:

```
android:lines="3"
```

Comment: Often better than `android:lines="3"` is `android:maxLines="3"`, providing a more flexible layout whilst still fixing the 'bug' in question.