# How do I make the colon vertical center in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` showing time. The time updates every second.

I used DIN font. I have set `TextView` to center align（vertical). Why does the colon align to the baseline? Who knows how to fix this issue?

[image]

**Update**

```
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48px"
                    android:layout_below="@id/temperature"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-5px"
                    android:fontFamily="DIN"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="39px" />
```

Comment: Depends on your XML. Post it

Comment: try to check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826411/how-do-i-align-text-view-to-be-in-center-vertically-of-two-numberpickers

Comment: If that is how the font renders the `:` glyph, then there's not much you can do without separating it into multiple views.

Comment: You haven't shown your XML so we don't know what you're exactly doing.

Comment: i have show my code @Sufian

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to align text vertically center in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108400/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-android)

Comment: As far as I understand, `center` aligns the entire text block in the view, not the individual characters.

Comment: Check the font for another colon--some fonts have a baseline-aligned colon *and* a more vertically-central colon, as each is useful for different purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default way how the font renders the colon character. There is no way in which you can change that, unless you create seperate TextViews for the colons. Alternatively you can use a different font and check if any of the other fonts actually centers the colon chararacter. Use the following to do this:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

For a better explanation of the fonts which can be used, you may check the [official documentation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-typeface).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to divide the whole TextView into 5 different TextViews and add `android:layout_marginTop="3px"` on the ones with numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Because the colon is such a simple shape you can build it from smaller elements, either text views, graphic primitives, or just two views, in a vertical linear layout.

For example, start by creating a simple dot as a shape drawable (dot.xml in the drawable folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ccc"/>
</shape>
```

Create a view with this drawable as the background (clock_dot.xml in the layout folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="3sp"
    android:layout_height="3sp"
    android:background="@drawable/dot"
    android:layout_margin="3sp"
    android:layout_weight="0" />
```

Stack two dots to create the colon character (clock_colon.xml in the layout folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/clock_dot"/>
    <include layout="@layout/clock_dot"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a text view with two digits (clock_digits.xml):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:textColor="#ccc"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="12" />
```

Then build a timer layout from the digits layout and the colon layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/clock_digits"/>
    <include layout="@layout/clock_colon"/>
    <include layout="@layout/clock_digits"/>
    <include layout="@layout/clock_colon"/>
    <include layout="@layout/clock_digits"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You get something like this:

[image: Screen shot of timer]

Comment: finally i use another font. but thanks very much. you ideal also helpful.